# How to set the timezone on sonata_type_datetime_picker

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

First question after using stackoverflow for years. Thanks for all the answers all over the years.

I have an issue with the sonata_type_datetime_picker.

My php.ini timezone is set to Europe/Paris.

In my sonata admin, i have a form to set date-start and date-end for a voucher.

```
            ->with('Conditions',['translation_domain' => 'SmallableAdminBundle'])
            ->add('startAt', 'sonata_type_datetime_picker', [
                'label' => 'form.commercialvoucher.startAt',
                'translation_domain' => 'SmallableAdminBundle',
                'format' => 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm',
                'attr' => [

                ],
            ])
            ->add('endAt', 'sonata_type_datetime_picker', [
                'label' => 'form.commercialvoucher.endAt',
                'translation_domain' => 'SmallableAdminBundle',
                'format' => 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm',
                'attr' => [

                ],
            ])
```

When i submit the form, seems the datetime are GMT time, so i lost basically one hour.

Example : When i edit my voucher, change the dates and submit, here with 10h00, i get 9:00.

```
    CRUDController.php on line 362:
CommercialVoucher {#241 ▼
      #id: 537287
      #code: "TEST_time"
      #name: "TEST_time"
      #description: "TEST_time"
      #validated: true
      #startAt: DateTime {#2791 ▼
        +"date": "2014-12-22 09:02:00.000000"
        +"timezone_type": 1
        +"timezone": "+00:00"
      }
      #endAt: DateTime {#2794 ▼
        +"date": "2014-12-22 09:00:00.000000"
        +"timezone_type": 1
        +"timezone": "+00:00"
      }
```

When i do another changes on the voucher, leaving the date unchanged, i get the right timezone.

```
    CRUDController.php on line 362:
CommercialVoucher {#241 ▼
  #id: 537287
  #code: "TEST_time"
  #name: "TEST_time"
  #description: "TEST_time"
  #validated: true
  #startAt: DateTime {#1397 ▼
    +"date": "2014-12-22 09:02:00.000000"
    +"timezone_type": 3
    +"timezone": "Europe/Paris"
  }
  #endAt: DateTime {#1398 ▼
    +"date": "2014-12-22 09:00:00.000000"
    +"timezone_type": 3
    +"timezone": "Europe/Paris"
  }
```

I tried a lot in my voucher admin, using the option format, date_format. I tried also to set timezone in the sonata config, but nothing worked so far.

Comment: This might be a bug. Could you please file a bugreport to the project? https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle

Answer (score -2):

I tried differents alternative solutions.

My best choice is to replace the sonata date picker by the default symfony widget.

```
                ->add('startAt', 'datetime', [
                'date_widget'       => 'single_text',
                'time_widget'       => 'single_text',
                'label' => 'form.commercialvoucher.startAt',
                'translation_domain' => 'SmallableAdminBundle',
                'attr' => [

                ],
            ])
```

And i also init the date values in my entity, so that users have most often only to change day and month.

```
    $startAt = new \DateTime('now');
    $endAt = new \DateTime('now');

    $startAt->setTime(0, 0, 0);
    $this->setStartAt($startAt);
    $endAt->setTime(23, 59, 59);
    $this->setEndAt($endAt);
```

[DateTime widget on the left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxVu8.png)

[Date and Time picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adGMB.png)